# How to publish a extension on VSCODE by myself

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I use a extension on VSCODE Market, but i think that it does not meet my needs.I want to customize it.

But, i have been confused for publishing npm package to VSCODE market. Who can tell me more details?

I had been PHPER, i had been publishd some packages to Composer.

Answer (score 9):

1. ready node environment, run cli: `npm install -g vsce`
2. ready publish resource,
3. open [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/VSCode), sign in,
4. click navbar YOUR NAME link (recommend), or menubar 'Publish extensions' link button;
5. "create new organization", continue until done ...
6. click organization, click the `User Settings` icon to the left of the avatar,
7. click 'Personal access tokens',
8. 'new token',

   - `name` is your extension name (kebab case),
   - `Organization` must select `All accessible organizations`, otherwise throw "Error: Failed Request: Unauthorized(401)";
   - `Scopes` → `Show all scopes` → "Marketplace" select `Acquire`+`Publish`, create...
9. copy token, backup to file or print it,
10. In the command line window,

    - run `vsce create-publisher YOUR-PUBLISH-NAME`,
    - "human-friendly name", enter,
    - "E-mail" input YOUR-EMAIL, enter,
    - "Personal Access Token", click the right mouse button to paste automatically, there will be a series of asterisk placeholders, enter,
    - prompt "Successfully", run `vsce publish -p YOUR-YOKEN`,
    - prompt "Successfully", completed the entire commit operation.
11. the next update, change 'package.json' 'version' field, only need run `vsce login YOUR-PUBLISH-NAME`, paste 'token', and run `vsce publish -p YOUR-YOKEN`.

The token can be regenerated on the management platform, step 7.

3/16/2022

---

1. remember YOUR-PUBLISH-NAME, YOUR-YOKEN.
2. [VS Code: publish extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/publish-extension)
3. `vsce -h` do more thing :)

Comment: Where can I get the publisher name from? I can't seem to find it anywhere!

Comment: @AhmedAl-haddad `vsce ls-publishers`, `vsce -h` view all commands

Answer (score 2):

The official site got you covered on publishing extensions, the whole process is very well documented here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/publish-extension

Comment: can you help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45442869/how-to-publish-a-lsp-language-server-on-vscode-as-we-do-extension