# How to publish a LSP language server on VSCODE as we do extension

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

Have been through official site, the whole process is very well documented for publishing extension : [vscode publish extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/publish-extension)

My doubt is regarding publish Language server(LSP) in vscode as file structure for LSP is different from that of Extension i.e extension just have Client but LSP has both Client and server directory separately as in [LSP Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-languageserver-node-example) and [Extension code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/decorator-sample).

Do i need to run `vsce publish` separately in `client` and `server` directory ?

Have been through various answers in stackoverflow  as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44813802/how-should-i-package-my-language-server-with-my-client).

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only need to publish the extension itself (the client) and not the server.

The LSP example is a little weird because it shows the client and server folders side by side, whereas the server is actually a dependency of the client. You can either pull in the server as a node module or copy the server JS into the client like the example does. Then just run `vsce publish` in the client to push everything up to the marketplace

Comment: just hoping if you could help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46356759/how-to-open-a-browser-within-vscode-just-like-another-editor-tab